# How do i get this or condition to work properly

Tags: java

So i'm making an uno game where the user can ony play a card that has the same value or the same color as the card in the stock pile
I currently have this as my code:

```
if(topPileCard().getColor()==card.getColor() || topPileCard().getValue() == card.getValue())
```

but if a user, for example, plays a green card the condition turns true only if the color matches and the value no longer works and vice versa 
Is there any way I can get around this?

and here is the code with uno cards class that has the getValue() and getColor() methods

```
public class UnoCard {
enum Color {
    RED, BLUE, GREEN, YELLOW,BLACK;

    private static final Color[] colors = Color.values();
    public static Color getColor(int i){
        return Color.colors[i];
    }
}

    enum Value {
        ZERO, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, SKIP, DRAW_TWO, REVERSE, WILD, WILD_FOUR;
        private static final Value[] values = Value.values();
        public static Value getValue(int i){
            return Value.values[i];
        }
}

private final Color color;
private final Value value;

public UnoCard(final Color color, final Value value){
    this.color = color;
    this.value = value;
}

public Color getColor(){
    return this.color;
}

public Value getValue(){
    return this.value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return color + "_" + value;
}
```

}

Comment: Does getColor() and getValue() return basic values (int, long, etc) or objects?

Comment: yes it's actually an enums with values and colors

Comment: Can you show the methods you call? Are you sure there isn't a string compare with == happening anywhere?

Comment: @Joee what is your problem exactly? Never enter in the condition ?

Comment: if i choose a color the condition basically becomes if(topPileCard().getColor()==card.getColor() ) and the value dosen't work anymore and vice versa

Comment: What do you mean by `the value doesn't work anymore` ?

Comment: If i play a green colored 5 i can no longer play cards with the value of 5 and i can only play cards that are green

Comment: i edited the post and added the class that has both the value and color methods

Comment: `If i play a green colored 5 i can no longer play cards with the value of 5 and i can only play cards that are green` here you're not using the uno rules...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using && instead of ||, || means "or" so neither of those two would be pick as true. && means "and", both of those conditions should meet before stating as true.

Comment: though i only need one condition to bet met for it to work either the color or the value matches

Comment: Try this:

boolean isAlreadyCorrect = false;
if(topPileCard().getColor()==card.getColor()){
   //Code here
   isAlreadyCorrect = true;
}
if(topPileCard().getValue()==card.getValue()&&isAlreadyCorrect==false){
  //Code here
}

Comment: This would kinda messy, but it works better than "||"

Comment: or i think the problem is the strings you compare.... try using ".contains" instead of "==" ex: topPileCard().getValue().toLowerCase().contains(card.getValue().toLowerCase())